# SharpDX.Toolkit throws error when loading effect. HRESULT: [0x80070057]

Tags: c#, hlsl, sharpdx

Here I have an application based on SharpDX, it's supposed to simulate particles using Computer Shader. I run it on Win 8.1 computer at Intel HD 3000 videocard. By the way, samples from `SharpDX` with Computer Shader and (or) Vertex Shader with requirments like `fx_4_0` or `Profile = 10.0` runs flawlesly.

The problem is, when it comes to loading the shader via `Content.Load<Effect>()` it throws an exception from `SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.CreateVertexShader()`

The exception is as follows:

```
[SharpDX.SharpDXException]  {
     SharpDX.SharpDXException: HRESULT: [0x80070057],
     Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_INVALIDARG/Invalid Arguments], 
     Message: The parameter is incorrect.
at SharpDX.Result.CheckError()
at SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.CreateVertexShader(IntPtr shaderBytecodeRef, PointerSize bytecodeLength, ClassLinkage classLinkageRef, VertexShader vertexShaderOut)
at SharpDX.Direct3D11.VertexShader..ctor(Device device, Byte[] shaderBytecode, ClassLinkage linkage)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.EffectPool.GetOrCompileShader(EffectShaderType shaderType, Int32 index, Int32 soRasterizedStream, StreamOutputElement[] soElements, String& profileError)
...
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Content.ContentManager.Load[T](String assetName, Object options)
```

Well, I've looked around for a while, but nowhere found a complite explanation - what exactly happens here?
As stated [here](https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/542466), the problem likely is with the VertexShader arguments, but as I'm newbie in shader development, I can't be shure. Nonetheless, here is the shader file:

```
struct Particle
{
    float3 Position;
    float3 Velocity;
};

StructuredBuffer<Particle> Particles : register(t0);
cbuffer Params : register(b0)
{
    float4x4 View;
    float4x4 Projection;
};

struct VertexInput
{
    uint VertexID : SV_VertexID;
};

struct PixelInput
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION; 
};

struct PixelOutput
{
    float4 Color : SV_TARGET0;
};

PixelInput DefaultVS(VertexInput input)
{
    PixelInput output = (PixelInput)0;

    Particle particle = Particles[input.VertexID];

    float4 worldPosition = float4(particle.Position, 1);
    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
    output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);
    return output;
}

PixelOutput DefaultPS(PixelInput input)
{
    PixelOutput output = (PixelOutput)0;

    output.Color = float4((float3)0.1, 1);

    return output;
}

technique ParticleRender
{
    pass DefaultPass
    {
        Profile = 10.0;
        VertexShader = DefaultVS;
        GeometryShader = 0;
        PixelShader = DefaultPS;
    }
}
```

I suppose, the problem lies in `VertexInput` structure, and `uint VertexID : SV_VertexID;` because in sapmles I've never met anything like this. By the vay, the application came from , so it you know russian, you are welcome to go see the origin :). Also, full solution can be loaded form [here](https://github.com/Mr-Destiny/GPUParticles/tree/minShader)

My code for effect loading is `Content.Load<Effect>("ParticleRender");`
and full stack trace is

```
at SharpDX.Result.CheckError()
at SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.CreateVertexShader(IntPtr shaderBytecodeRef, PointerSize bytecodeLength, ClassLinkage classLinkageRef,  VertexShader vertexShaderOut)
at SharpDX.Direct3D11.VertexShader..ctor(Device device, Byte[] shaderBytecode, ClassLinkage linkage)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.EffectPool.GetOrCompileShader(EffectShaderType shaderType, Int32 index, Int32 soRasterizedStream,  StreamOutputElement[] soElements, String& profileError)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.EffectPass.InitStageBlock(StageBlock stageBlock, Logger logger)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.EffectPass.Initialize(Logger logger)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.Effect.InitializeFrom(Effect effectDataArg, Effect cloneFromEffect)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.Effect.CreateInstanceFrom(GraphicsDevice device, EffectData effectData, EffectPool effectPool)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.Effect..ctor(GraphicsDevice device, EffectData effectData, EffectPool effectPool)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.EffectContentReader.ReadContent(IContentManager readerManager, GraphicsDevice device, ContentReaderParameters&  parameters)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.GraphicsResourceContentReaderBase`1.SharpDX.Toolkit.Content.IContentReader.ReadContent(IContentManager  readerManager, ContentReaderParameters& parameters)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Content.ContentManager.LoadAssetWithDynamicContentReader(Type assetType, String assetName, Stream stream, Object options)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Content.ContentManager.Load(Type assetType, String assetName, Object options)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Content.ContentManager.Load[T](String assetName, Object options)
at GPUParticles.Logic.LoadContent() in f:\Users\Maxim\UserData\Programming\GPUParticlesSources\GPUParticles\Logic.cs:line 63
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Game.InitializeBeforeRun()
at SharpDX.Toolkit.GameWindowDesktop.RunRenderLoop()
at SharpDX.Toolkit.GameWindowDesktop.Run()
at SharpDX.Toolkit.GamePlatform.Run(GameContext gameContext)
at SharpDX.Toolkit.Game.Run(GameContext gameContext)
at GPUParticles.Program.Main() in f:\Users\Maxim\UserData\Programming\GPUParticlesSources\GPUParticles\Program.cs:line 22}  SharpDX.SharpDXException
```

Comment: Can you post the code that calls `CreateVertexShader`, please?

Comment: @ChrisMantle , it's pretty complicated - `CreateVertexShader` calls from inside the `SharpDX`. My code is `Content.Load<Effect>("ParticleRender");`, and I added full stack trace

Comment: Whenever you have a SharpDXException, please follow "[How to debug a SharpDXException?](http://sharpdx.org/forum/4-general/1774-how-to-debug-a-sharpdxexception)"

Answer (score 3):

just stumbled over this as I had a similar error with monogame and trying to load a shader.

In my case this error was related to the graphicsDevice profile not being set to

> HiDef

```
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    graphics.GraphicsProfile = GraphicsProfile.HiDef;
```

Cheers,

Stephan

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever you have a SharpDXException, please follow ["How to debug sharpDX exception"](http://sharpdx.org/forum/4-general/1774-how-to-debug-a-sharpdxexception)

It turned out that in reality the Intel 3000 do not have the support of the ComputeShader, despite having the support of the DirectX 10.0